# Menu doesn't align in right side

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, menu, menuitem

In my app design with Android Studio - Kotlin I need force three dots of menu align in the right side but it's appear in the center, like this image:

[Menu center align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Dow.jpg)

How align in the right side?

Edit:
My activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBkgrdApp"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="?attr/actionModeSplitBackground"
    android:tint="@android:color/background_light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewListas"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried:           
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"

Comment: Why do you use `layout_width="0dp"` in `AppBarLayout` and `layout_width="wrap_content"` in `ToolBar`? I would think that is causing the problem. You should replace both with "match_parent".

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, `android:gravity="right"` is different from `android:layout_gravity="right"`.

The first one affects the position of the text itself within the View, so if you want it to be right-aligned, then `layout_width=` should be either `"fill_parent"` or `"match_parent"`.
The second one affects the View's position inside its parent, in other words - aligning the object itself (edit box or text view) inside the parent view.

Comment: Thanks @JEGO but I have had tried:  android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"     no success

Answer (score 0):

Thank's @David Wasser,

I solved the problem by adjusting it like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBkgrdApp"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

This way showed the three points in the right side.